# Disable check for certain file type

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, syntastic

I have an .epp file that's a shell script with Ruby embedded inside. I'm guessing the "shebang" line (`#!`) activates the sh check.

Is it possible to ignore/disable checks for .epp files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use autocomand in your vimrc

```
augroup epp_file_type
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter *.epp set ft=
augroup END
```

It will unset file type when buffer is opend by the first time.

Comment: Or just set `b:syntastic_mode` to `passive` instead of killing `filetype`.  That's what the manual recommends.

Comment: @lcd047 Wouldn't that disable syntastic completely?

Comment: @CorexCain No worries. What @lcd047 suggested will disable syntastic only for the current buffer (as it is `b:` variable which means it is scoped to the buffer).